# Unable to use my mouse with automation applications like xdotool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, python3, xdotool

So, I just installed Ubuntu as a dual boot system with windows 10 on my PC. I installed xdotool on it and proceeded to use it. I tried "xdotool mousemove 0 0" but nothing happened. My mouse did not move and xdotool did not show any output. Later i tried using pynput with python to do what i wanted to do, But it failed as well. It showed no output and my mouse cursor did not move. I don't see any errors. I also tried using the script as root, then it shows this error:

````
  File "/home/skzafir/Documents/Python/Test/mouse.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pynput/_util/__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError: this platform is not supported: ('failed to acquire X connection: Can\'t connect to display ":0": b\'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified\\n\'', DisplayConnectionError(':0', b'Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified\n'))

Try one of the following resolutions:

 * Please make sure that you have an X server running, and that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly```
````

Comment: It looks you're using Wayland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [@ArkadiuszDrabczyk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/72304/arkadiusz-drabczyk) was right. I was using Wayland since Ubuntu uses Wayland by default. I just switched to Xorg and it started working fine.

To switch to Xorg:

1. Log out of ubuntu (You can also restart but its not necessary)
2. Click the cog wheel below the password section
3. Click Ubuntu on Xorg

This will set Xorg as default so you don't have to constantly switch to it.

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/switch-xorg-wayland-ubuntu1710/